# Different ANR per 1k when full rollout 100%

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, android-anr-dialog

I have a problem with ANR per 1.000 after releasing 100% rollout APK, which has a big difference from when I launched 50% rollout. I think it happens because Google Play Console just accumulate from the first version of the release, is it a bug? How to see the ANR per 1.000 as a benchmark for our app's performance? thank you [Rollout Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSZVo.jpg)

Comment: Please could you provide  another screenshot when the rollout is at 100% for the APK so we can compare it with the one you've already provided for 50% rollout. I certainly saw the rates per 1000 vary at different stages of a rollout for an app with an install base of around 2M users. At the time (about 18 months ago) I learned when releases showed early signs of problems through watching the graphs change during the rollouts.

Answer (score 1):

It just takes time for the crashes and ANRs to propagate, plus it takes time for users to actually update to the new version, so you really can't compare the stats.

The only way you could test it would be to do a 50% rollout, wait for something like a week, and see what your crash and ANR rate is.

Then, increment the build number, and create a new release for it. Release it to production with 100% rollout right away, and wait another week.

At that point, you'll have 2 versions that are internally identical, but you can compare their stats apples-to-apples

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually I have run for 2 week for 50% rollout and yesterday I just update it to 100% rollout and this happen.

Comment: like I said, you would have to change the buid#, and than make a whole new release with 100% rollout. There's no other way to compare them